# New Distributed cache API Hadoop2 backcompatibility

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I would like to know if new Distributed cache API is back-compatible with Hadoop 1?

If I change my code adhering the new API (since the old one is deprecated) will it work on Hadoop 1 cluster?

By new I mean:

```
Configuration conf = getConf();
...
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
...
job.addCacheFile(new URI(filename));
```

Comment: By "new distributed cache API" do you mean Job#setCacheFiles and its ilk or something else?

Comment: @AngusDavis I have edited my answer.